# XML and XSL[ I have a img src attribute in the xsl stylesheet and I want to assign it to xsl:variable in the same style sheet ]

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I’ve been trying to assign my

<xsl:variable name=“Input” select=“document.getElementByTag(‘img’).src” />

xsl variable a value based on the element img src attribute that changes depending on my buttons created by xsl:for-each...etc. Please I need help.

The element img and xsl:variable are in the same xsl stylesheet

Comment: Client-side Javascript provides a `document` object with a method `getElementsByTagName` (not one called `getElementByTagName`) but it is not clear why you expect to able to use client-side Javascript APIs in the XPath expression of the `select` attribute of an XSLT variable.

Comment: _"The element img and xsl:variable are in the same xsl stylesheet"_ This sugest that the `img` element is a [literal result element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#literal-result-element) in the stylesheet and the last one is dynamically generated (otherwise you should know in advance the value of `src` attribute). The XSLT specification states that the [`document()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#function-document) function invocation with an empty string argument _"refers to the root node of the stylesheet"_

Comment: The element <img> will have its src attribute dynamically changed by the user with multiple buttons assigning different pictures to the element <img> at onclick. I hoped to have the xsl variable named Input act as a dynamic variable utilized in an xpath call to an xml but with the path varying based on the buttons. I have not found a way to cross JavaScript and the xsl variable